# How do i install bitcoind on my redhat linux server?

Tags: bitcoind, server, linux, installation

I have recently created an api that runs the bitcoind commands. I had it running on another server, but it was setup by someone else. I have been searching for sensible instructions on how to install bitcoind on my new server, but can't find any.

Comment: I don't understand your question. To run bitcoind on your server, you just... run it? Like, `./bitcoind`? What's the problem?

Comment: how do i install i guess is a better way to word it?

Comment: and for some reference i am using an amazon ec2 server so i am doing everything through terminal

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you can install it from a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git clone git://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin/src/
make -f makefile.unix
sudo cp bitcoind /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: i i get this error: g++ -c -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/ec2-user/bitcoin/src -I/home/ec2-user/bitcoin/src/obj -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/home/ec2-user/bitcoin/src/leveldb/include -I/home/ec2-user/bitcoin/src/leveldb/helpers -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/alert.d -o obj/alert.o alert.cpp
alert.cpp:5:29: fatal error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/alert.o] Error 1

Comment: i am not using ubunuto as far as i can tell. I believe its redhat linux.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Git

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

### Dependency Build Instructions: Ubuntu & Debian

Build requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

for Ubuntu 12.04+:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

db4.8 packages are available at:
 https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin

Ubuntu 12.10 has packages for libdb5.1-dev and libdb5.1++-dev,
 but using these will break binary wallet compatibility, and is not recommended.

for other Ubuntu & Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8++-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost1.37-dev
```

(If using Boost 1.37, append `-mt` to the boost libraries in the makefile)

Optional:

```
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev (see USE_UPNP compile flag)
```

### Retrieve and compile Bitcoin source

```
git clone git://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin/src/
make -f makefile.unix
sudo cp bitcoind /usr/local/bin
```

(much of this pulled directly from the [build-unix.txt](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt#L55) instructions)

Comment: i am using redhat linux so i am not sure if these instructions apply?

Comment: @AndrewFont they do not. However, we are going outside bitcoin's scope, you should ask in a generic linux site...

Answer (score 0):

From another site (SO clone - http://www.rugatu.com/questions/15712/how-to-install-bitcoind-in-linux):

Here the step-by-step setup. Follow the procedure as root, or as user but use sudo when needed. I'll use sudo here.

1) Add the experimental repository to get the latest version of bitcoind. To do so, run nano (or your preferred text editor) to open the sources.list:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add to the end of the file the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ experimental main
```

save and exit.

2) Run the update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3) Install bitcoind from the experimental repo:

```
sudo apt-get install -t experimental bitcoind
```

4) comment out the experimental repo line in sources.list.

Comment: Apt? Redhat? You're missing something.

Comment: whoops! good call - sorry. I saw another answer mentioning apt-get

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just download an RPM that does all of this for you. I provide one on my website for both i686 and x86_64:

```
# 32 bit
yum install http://tvdw.eu/bitcoin-0.8.1-1.el6.i686.rpm
# 64 bit
yum install http://tvdw.eu/bitcoin-0.8.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

# Now you can just run the client
bitcoind
```

These RPMs aren't signed, so install them at your own risk.

---

Don't want the RPM? Understandable. Get the compiled tarball from the bitcoin site ([direct link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.1/bitcoin-0.8.1-linux.tar.gz/download))

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.1/bitcoin-0.8.1-linux.tar.gz/download
tar -xfv bitcoin-0.8.1-linux.tar.gz
cd bitcoin-0.8.1-linux
./32/bitcoind
```